# Use subdirectories with classpathPrefix in maven pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I am using the following to build up a classpath in my maven pom.xml

```
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix> 
                    </manifest>
```

There is a directory under 'lib' which I also want to add to the classpath but it doesn't seem to pick it up.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why does it seem that it doesn't pick it up? Didn't it appear in the manifest.mf? [This](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-manifest-file-with-maven/) could help you

Comment: No - doesn't appear in the manifest

Comment: sorry, correction - it does appear in the manifest but it doesn't add the  the directory under lib to the path, so lib/myfolder/myjar.jar becomes lib/myjar.jar in the manifest - it doesn't preserve the folder path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a directory to your Class-Path in your Manifest file, you can add something like this to your pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>your_main_class</mainClass>
                </manifest>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Class-Path>lib/myfolder/</Class-Path>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Comment: That will load all the dependencies in lib/myfolder/ but none of the dependencies in lib/. I need it to support both lib/ and lib/myfolder/.

Comment: Did you try with <Class-Path>lib/</Class-Path> or adding the both of them?

Comment: Adding multiple entries doesn't seem to make any difference, it only picks up the last entry:                                                                                                                   `<Class-Path>lib/</Class-Path>
                            <Class-Path>lib/mylib1</Class-Path>
                            <Class-Path>lib/mylib2</Class-Path>`                 In this case only mylib2 is put on the class path

Comment: I do not know if it works, but what happens if you put something like this: <Class-Path>lib/mylib1 lib/mylib2</Class-Path>

Comment: It just prepends the classpath with lib lib/mylib1 lib/lib2.: `Class-Path: lib/ lib/restemulator_deps lib/testlink_deps ant-junit-1.6
 .5.jar ant-1.6.2.jar checkstyle-4.4.jar` The path to the jar is not preserved. It lists out all the jars in those locations but without the path to the jar.

Comment: I can not help you, sorry. Maybe this thread could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626883/maven-error-trying-to-adding-arbitrary-classpath-in-manifest-mf

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with jar plugin. Try assembly plugin, it is more flexible